# proof using Brownian motion scaling property

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am trying to prove $A_t^+$ has the same distribution as $tA_1^+$ using the scaling property, where
$$
A_t^+ = \int_0^t\mathcal 1_{[0,\infty)}(W_s)\,ds
$$
I tried to scale the Brownian motion but it cannot lead to the right conclusion. I wonder which step is wrong. Here is what I attempted.
$$
\begin{aligned}
tA_1^+ & = t\int_0^1\mathcal 1_{[0,\infty)}(W_s)\,ds \\
& = \sqrt{t}\int_0^1\mathcal 1_{[0,\infty)}(\sqrt{t} W_{s})\,ds \\
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\int_0^1\mathcal 1_{[0,\infty)}(W_{ts}) \,d(ts) \\ 
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\int_0^t\mathcal 1_{[0,\infty)}(W_u) \,du \\ 
& = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}A_t^+
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see, you let $\sqrt{t}$ enter the parenthesis of the indicator, which does not make sense. And you don't need that to have the indicator $1_{ \ge 0}(\sqrt{t}W_s)$ because it already is:
$$
1_{ \ge 0}(W_s) = 1_{ \ge 0}(\sqrt{t}W_s)
$$

Answer (score 0):

For $t>0$.
\begin{align}
A_t^+ &= \int_0^t\mathbb{1}({W_s \geq 0)} ds\\
&=^{u = s/t} t\int_0^1\mathbb{1}({W_{ut} \geq 0})du\\
&= t\int_0^1{\mathbb{1}\left(\frac{W_{ut}}{\sqrt{t}}\geq 0\right)}du\\
&=^{(d)} t\int_0^1{\mathbb{1}(\tilde{W}_{u} \geq 0)}du\\
\end{align}
In the last equality, we use the scaling property of the BM i.e. for $u\geq0$, $\tilde{W}_u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}W_{ut}$ is again a BM.